# Inverses and cancellation in modular arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I was working on a problem that resulted in the calculation:
$20 \equiv 10x \pmod{11}$.

I got the answer $x \equiv 2 \pmod{11}$ with the thought process: Since $10$ is a factor of $20$ I can rewrite $20 \pmod{11}$ as $10x \pmod{11}$ with $x=2$. But isn't this basically the same as using division, which we aren't supposed to do in modular spaces?

If I solve by multiplying $20$ by the multiplicative inverse of $10 \pmod{11}$ which is $10$, I get $200 \pmod{11}$ which simplifies to $2 \pmod{11}$ anyway. Did these numbers just happen to be the same or is my original method valid?

Comment: normal math must be preserved in modular arithmetic.  otherwise we could use modular arithmetic to disprove thing like -1 is 2 less than 1. etc.  you can rewrite $20\equiv10x\pmod{11}$ as $20\equiv-2(-5)x\pmod{11}$ which means x must be the modular inverse of -5 ( aka 6 in the positive version) mod 11.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Try putting {} around the number when using `pmod` (e.g. $\pmod{11}$ (`\pmod{11}`) vs $\pmod11$ (`pmod11`)

Comment: sorry about that @2012ssohn I forgot about that  part of why I don't like some commands.

Comment: Modular arithmetic can be extended to certain rational numbers, and under this interpretation division and multiplication by inverse is the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your original method works only because $10$ has an inverse modulo $11$. You wrote $20 \equiv 10x \pmod{11}$ as
$$ 10(2) \equiv 10x \pmod{11}. $$
Now, using the fact that $10^{-1}$ exists, we can multiply by it to conclude $2 \equiv x \pmod{11}$. If $10$ wasn't invertible, we wouldn't be able to conclude this. For instance, $2(2) \equiv 2(3) \pmod{2}$, but $2\not\equiv 3 \pmod{2}$.

Answer (score 3):

Invertible elements are always cancellable: $\,a^{-1}$ times $\,ab\equiv ac\,\Rightarrow\,b\equiv c,\,$ i.e. $\,x\mapsto ax\,$ is $1$-$1$. Furthermore: $\ a\,$ is invertible mod $m\iff a\,$ is coprime to $m\iff x\mapsto ax\,$ is onto, see

**Theorem** $\ $ The following are equivalent for integers $\rm\:a, m.$

$(1)\rm\ \ \ gcd(a,m) = 1$
$(2)\rm\ \ \ a\:$ is invertible $\rm\ \ \ \,(mod\ m)$
$(3)\rm\ \ \ x\to ax\:$ is $\:1$-$1\:$ $\rm\,(mod\ m),\,$ i.e. $\rm\,a\,$ is cancellable $\!\bmod m,\,$ i.e. $\rm\,ax\equiv ay\Rightarrow x\equiv y$
$(4)\rm\ \ \ x\to ax\:$ is onto $\rm\,(mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\  (1\Rightarrow 2)\  $ By [Bezout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezout%27s_identity) $\rm\, gcd(a,m)\! =\! 1\Rightarrow ja\!+\!km =\! 1\,$ for $\rm\,j,k\in\Bbb Z\,$ $\rm\Rightarrow ja\equiv 1\!\pmod{\! m}$
$(2\Rightarrow 3)\ \ \ \rm ax \equiv ay\,\Rightarrow\,a(x\!-\!y)\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\,x\!-\!y\equiv 0\,$ by multiplying by $\rm\,a^{-1}$
$(3\Rightarrow 4)\ \  $ Every $1$-$1$ function on a finite set is onto (pigeonhole).
$(4\Rightarrow 1)\ \ \ \rm x\to ax\,$ is onto, so $\rm\,aj\equiv 1,\,$ some $\rm\,j,\,$ i.e. $\,aj\!+\!km = 1,\,$ some $\rm\,k,\,$ so $\rm\gcd(a,m)=1$

[See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/664094/242) for a conceptual proof of said Bezout identity for the gcd.

**Beware** if $\,a\,$ isn't invertible it fails;  then $\ 1< d\mid a,m\,$ ao $\,dx\equiv 0\,$ has two roots $\,x\equiv 0,m/d\ $ so we can't cancel $\,d\,$ to deduce $\,x\equiv 0$

Recall also that [inverses are unique](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3152344/242) when they exist.

Comment: See also [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/848429/242)

Answer (score 1):

Let $m$ be any integer for which you can define equivalence modulo $m$
in the usual way.
If $a = by$ in ordinary arithmetic over integers $a,$ $b,$ and $y,$
and if $x \equiv y \pmod m,$
then $a \equiv bx \pmod m.$

Your method of solving $20 \equiv 10x \pmod {11}$
basically comes down to the observation
that $y = 2$ is a solution to the equation $20 = 10y.$
That is enough to conclude that $x \equiv 2 \pmod {11}$
is a solution of $20 \equiv 10x \pmod {11}.$

Notice the careful wording: "*a* solution" rather than "*the* solution."
(In slightly more formal language, "a member of the solution set"
rather than "the one and only member of the solution set.")

For example, if we apply this method to the problem
$4 \equiv 2x \pmod6,$ it will correctly tell us that $x\equiv2 \pmod6$
is a solution; but $x\equiv5 \pmod6$ is also a solution, although this method will never inform us about that solution.

The fact that $10$ has an inverse modulo $11$ is what makes your solution *the* solution rather than just *a* solution.