# Modular Inverse Notation

Tags: notation, modular-arithmetic

I know how to get a inverse but I don't know how to put it into equations.  So let $5^{-1}$ exist in mod m.  Is $5^{-1}$, $1/5$, $-5$, or the modular inverse number.  To put it more generally, is $5^{-1}$ a notation or really a power of $-1$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $-5$ is the additive inverse; the others are the multiplicative inverse.  And $5^{-1}$ behaves like a power in that $5^{-1}5^n\equiv5^{n-1}\pmod m$ when $5^{-1}$ exists

Comment: Welcome to MSE! For best results I suggest writing in Mathjax. Here is a [quick tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to get you started. To answer your question, $5^{-1}$ usually denotes the multiplicative inverse of 5 in any number system.

Comment: It can be either - see the linked dupes for the fractional viewpoint.  Recall the [modular inverses are *unique*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3128681/uniqueness-of-modular-multiplicative-inverse) so there is no inconsistency.