# If $j$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$, and $37j = 12k$, prove $j + k$ is divisible by $7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

My thinking:

$37j = 12k \rightarrow \:j+k=\frac{49j}{12}$

$\frac{49j}{12}$ = $7\left(\frac{7j}{12}\right)$

Here's where I'm stuck. How do I show that $\left(\frac{7j}{12}\right) \in \mathbb{N}$

Thank you.

Comment: $\!\bmod 7\!:\,\ \color{#0a0}{\overbrace{37}^{\large \equiv\,\ 2}}j\,\equiv\!\color{#c00}{\overbrace{12}^{\large\equiv\ -2}}k\!\iff \color{#0a0}2j\equiv \color{#c00}{-2}k\!\!\overset{\div\ 2}\iff j\equiv  -k\iff j+k\equiv 0.\,$ Note $\,2\,$ is coprime to the modulus $\,7\,$ so it is [invertible so cancellable](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2383809/242). See the linked dupe for general methods for solving linear congruences (above we solved for $\,j\,).  \ $

Comment: I haven't learned mod yet in my class. I'm supposed to do it without that.

Comment: The idea of the above congruence proof is simple: $\,2(j\!+\!k)\,$ and $\,37j\!-\!12k\,$ differ by a multiple of $7$, viz. $7(5j\!-\!2k),\,$ so since $7$ divides $\,37j\!-\!12k\,(= 0)$ it must also divide $\,2(j\!+\!k),\,$ so $\,7\mid j\!+\!k,\,$ by $\,7\mid 2n\Rightarrow 7\mid n,\,$ by $\,(7,2)=1\,$ & [Euclid's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1216213/242) (or directly: $\,7\mid 4(2n)\!-\!7n = n)$. Congruence language simplifies arguments about divisibility *relations* by transforming then into more intuitive *equation* arithmetic, e.g. in my prior comment we solved a linear *equation*

Comment: Directly: $\ j\!+\!k = 4\:\!(\overbrace{37j\!-\!12k}^{\large\color{#c00} 0})\!-\!\color{#c00}7^2(3j\!-\!k)$ is divisible by $\color{#c00}7$ since both summands are. $\ \ $

Comment: To complete the proof your way (using fractions) note that

$$ \dfrac{37}{12} = \dfrac{k}j\,\overset{+\ 1}\Longrightarrow\, \dfrac{49}{12} =\dfrac{j+k}j\qquad  $$

but $\,(49,12)=1\,$ thus $\,49/12\,$ is reduced, [therefore](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/825871/242) $\,49\,\mid\, j+k\ \ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are given $37j=12k$, so $12\mid 37j$.

Observe that $(12,37)=1$. Then $12\mid 37j$ implies that $12\mid j$, so $j=12n$, for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$. It is easy to see then that $\frac{7j}{12}\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score -1):

If $37j=12k$, then $k=37k_1$ and $j=12j_1$ for some $k_1,j_1\in \mathbb{N}$. Then try to show that $k_1=j_1$ and hence $k+j=49k_1$ and you are done.

Moreover, we have shown that $49\mid k+j$.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score -1):

Given that $j$ and $k$ are natural numbers satisfying the relation
$$
37 j = 12 k 
$$

This shows that $j = 12 m$ and $k = 37 m$ for some $m \in \mathbf{N}$.

Now, we note that
$$
j + k = 12 m + 37 m = 49 m \tag{1}
$$

By division algorithm, it is immediate from (1) that $49$ is a divisor of $j + k$.

We have shown that $49 \ | \ j + k$.

Comment: There is a typo in your reasoning. You probably meant that $j=12m$ and $k=37m$. The rest looks fine

Comment: I am sorry - i was doing it mentally -  I made a typo.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).