# Suppose that f is a function from A to B, where A and B are finite sets |A| = |B|. Show that f is one-to-one if and only if it is onto.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Suppose that f is a function from A to B, where A and B are finite
>   sets |A| = |B|. Show that f is one-to-one if and only if it is onto.

Lets say we were to translate this statement using variables. Where:

a: f is a function from A to B, where A and B are finite sets |A| = |B|

b: f is one-to-one

c: f is onto

Now, I believe this statement translates to "a -> (b <-> c)" symbolically. **Is this correct?**

This would mean that we need to prove the two sub-statements "a -> (b -> c)" and "a -> (c -> b)" in order to prove the overall statement "a -> (b <-> c)".

To prove "a -> (b -> c)", I'm thinking of first showing that "b -> c" is true using a proof by contradiction. We would then get "a -> T", which is always true (trivial proof). **Is this correct?**

To prove "a -> (c -> b)", we would use the same procedure.

**Is this what the top answerer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/337314/279174) does?**

Questions highlighted in bold.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/989059/589.

Comment: @lhf Interesting!