# Let $m, x$ be positive integers such that $GCD(m, x) = 1$. Then $x$ has a multiplicative inverse modulo $m$, and it is unique (modulo $m$).

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

The theorem quoted in the title, was actually stated differently in the problem I was reading. The original statement was as follows:

> Let $m$ be a positive integer and let $S$ denote the set of positive integers less than $m$ that are *relatively prime* to $m$. Prove that for each $x$ in $S$, there exists a unique $y$ in $S$ such that $xy$ is *congruent to* $1$ modulo $m$.

The proof that I have encountered, addresses the statement of the theorem given in the title:

> Consider the sequence of $m$ numbers $0, x, 2x, \ldots, (m−1)x$. We claim that these are all distinct modulo $m$. Since there are only $m$ distinct values modulo $m$, it must then be the case that $ax = 1 \mod m$ for
>   exactly one $a$ (modulo m). This $a$ is the unique *multiplicative inverse*.
>   To verify the above claim, suppose that $ax = bx \mod m$ for two distinct values $a,b$ in the range $0 \le a,b \le m−1$. Then we would have $(a−b)x = 0 \mod m$, or equivalently, $(a−b)x = km$ for some integer $k$ (possibly zero or negative). But since $x$ and $m$ are *relatively prime*, it follows that $a−b$ must be an integer multiple of $m$. This is not possible since $a,b$ are distinct non-negative integers less than $m$.

As far as I can understand, this only proves that $x$ always has a unique *multiplicative inverse*, but not that this inverse belongs to the set $S$ (as defined by the original statement of the theorem).

I understand that this proof is correct, and I can see why it would work when $m$ is *prime* (as the set $S$ would then contain all positive integers less than $m$), however when $m$ is any positive integer the set $S$ would not necessarily contain $m-1$ elements.

Therefore, it seems as if the proof does not exclude the possibility that the *multiplicative inverse* is not itself *relatively prime* to $m$.

Comment: $ax+my = 1\,\Rightarrow\,\gcd(a,m) = 1,\,$ so $\,a\in S\,$ by $\,0\le a < m\ \ $

Comment: You statement: *"Prove that for each m in S, there exists a unique m in S such that xy is congruent to 1 modulo m. "* doesn't make sense. Perhaps you wanted to define $S$ differently.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3216109/242) for a clearer more detailed presentation of this proof (and equivalents).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you accept that for any $x\in S$ s  that there exist a $y\in \{1,\cdots, m-1\}$ such that $xy\equiv 1 \pmod m$ but you are not convinced that $y\in S$

what is then $\gcd(y,m)$?

We know that $xy - pm= 1$ (for some integer $p$) therefore $\gcd(y,m) = 1$

Comment: Is the fact that xy - pm = 1 ⇒ gcd(y, m) = 1 based on a theorem itself? I think it makes sense since if y and m shared a factor k greater than 1, then that could be factored out so that k(xq - pr) = 1, which would imply that k = 1 (along with xq-pr =1) anyway.

Comment: It falls out from the application of the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: @F.Munnelly It's the trivial direction of the Bezout identity (when stated in $\!\iff\!$ form). But it is an immediate consequence of divisibility laws: $\,d\mid y,m\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid xy,pm\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid xy+pm = 1.\,$ Equivalently, sets of (common) multiples $M$ are closed under both addition, and multiplication by any integer, therefore $\,y,m\in M\,\Rightarrow\, xy+pm\in M\,$ for any $x,p\in\Bbb Z\ $ (here $M = d\Bbb Z = $ all multiples of $d).\,$ Such sets of (common) multiples are prototypical examples of [ideals.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory))

Comment: @DougM One doesn't need the Euclidean algorithm or Bezout to deduce that trivial direction - see above.